# How to calculate the mean of rows with rows having same content from Columns A to C in Excel using python?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, mean

I am writing a program to calculate the mean between rows (with several conditions)of each column from columns D to G.
In this program, as shown in the picture below, the calculation for the mean can only be done when columns A, B, and C are having the same content.
Hence, row 2 and row 6; row 3 and row 7; row 4 and row 8; row 5 and row 9 have the same title, PC, and rd/wr, respectively.
I did some research and I know that the fact that python counts row number one as 0. The index should have a form of n+1.

[Excel file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCo9U.png)

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_excel('Report_testing.xlsx')
x = df.iloc[[1, 5], [2, 6], [3, 7], [4, 8]].mean() #I hardcode the location as I still have no idea to set the condition from Columns A to C
print(x)
```

Expected Output:

```
Test_1  PC0 Write Latency   89    1844  628.5   292
Test_1  PC1 Write Latency   90.5  2383  669.5   362.5
Test_2  PC0 Write Latency   89    1527  577.5   275
Test_2  PC1 Write Latency   90.5  1513  577.5   271
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G65AU.png)

However, when I compile my code, it has an error and the mean cannot be calculated. How should I amend my code so that the mean can be processed accordingly? I am also having trouble writing the conditions so that the mean only processes the row with the same content from columns A to C.

Content of Excel File:

```
title   pc  rd/wr           Min Max  Avg Std_dev
Test_1  PC0 Write Latency   88  1838 634 297
Test_1  PC1 Write Latency   92  2363 661 369
Test_2  PC0 Write Latency   90  1524 576 273
Test_2  PC1 Write Latency   94  1526 568 267
Test_1  PC0 Write Latency   90  1850 623 287
Test_1  PC1 Write Latency   89  2403 678 356
Test_2  PC0 Write Latency   88  1530 579 277
Test_2  PC1 Write Latency   87  1500 587 275
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why don't you try a groupby with the columns A,B,C and as an aggregation you do mean() ?

Comment: @DataSciRookie Can you show me what you mean by that? I have no idea what you are sharing about.

Comment: @DataSciRookie Your idea does not match my requirement and it causes the question to be deleted. Please, can you request to undelete my question?